Is there a way to get the original function and its signature using reflect
I want to create a funcMap from all methods of a particular struct.
I have the following code:
type templateFuncs struct{}

func (t templateFuncs) UnescapeHTML(html string) template.HTML {
    html = strings.ReplaceAll(html, " ", "")
    html = strings.ReplaceAll(html, "\n\n", "\n")
    return template.HTML(html)
}

func (h *Handler) templateFuncs() template.FuncMap {
    funcMap := make(template.FuncMap)
    tplFuncs := &templateFuncs{}

    rType := reflect.TypeOf(tplFuncs)

    for i := 0; i < rType.NumMethod(); i++ {
        method := rType.Method(i)
        funcMap[method.Name] = method.Func.Interface()
        fmt.Printf("method %#v", method)
    }

    return funcMap
}

However, this assigns a function where the first argument is a pointer receiver.
"UnescapeHTML":(func(*http.templateFuncs, string) template.HTML)(0x10333eb40)

Is there a way to assign the original function with just the string argument to the funcMap? Is there a better way for approaching this problem?

Use ValueOf instead of TypeOf. Note however that if the method modifies the receiver this may have unintended consequences and is potentially subject to race condition if tplFuncs is shared by more than one goroutine.
v := &templateFuncs{}
type_method := reflect.TypeOf(v).Method(0).Func.Interface()
value_method := reflect.ValueOf(v).Method(0).Interface()

fmt.Printf("type_method=%T\n", type_method)
fmt.Printf("value_method=%T\n", value_method)

# type_method=func(*main.templateFuncs, string) template.HTML
# value_method=func(string) template.HTML

https://go.dev/play/p/U5jQ67BbCCG
